# Invoke POSIX's `exec` function in .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

How can I make the system call `exec`, or any of its siblings, in a C# (.NET Core) app that runs on Linux?

Comment: You P/Invoke them, like any other native function

Comment: I'm looking for a native API in .NET Core - does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

You could call exec as a bash command like [this](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/)